# How can we scrape minified HTML with BeautifulSoup and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML table like below:

```
<table class="pull-right table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="cost-comparison-table">
    <tr>
        <td> ABC
        <td>USD 17000
    <tr>
        <td> DEF
        <td>USD 4000
    <tr>
        <td> GHI
        <td>USD 5000
    <tr>
        <td> JKL
        <td>USD 18000
    <tr>
        <td> MNO
        <td>USD 19000
    <tr>
        <td> PQR
        <td>USD 10500
        </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to scrape the HTML formatted in this way? Actually, this is minified version of the HTML. To be noted - in HTML5 closing tags like `li`, `tr`, `td`, `br`, `img` is not mandatory.

I need to create a dictionary from the table contents, my code so far:

```
tds = [row.findAll('td') for row in soup.findAll('tr')]
results = { td[0].string: td[1].string for td in tds }
```

Comment: can you just not use pandas?

Comment: where does it say you can exclude closing `table`? I'm checking against: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: @QHarr Here it is - https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/to-close-or-not-to-close-tags-in-html5

Comment: yeah, `table` is not part of the list.

Comment: Yeah @QHarr, I checked again, and so made the necessary changes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas' `.read_html()` to parse that.

**Given:**

```
html = '''<table class="pull-right table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="cost-comparison-table">
    <tr>
        <td> ABC
        <td>USD 17000
    <tr>
        <td> DEF
        <td>USD 4000
    <tr>
        <td> GHI
        <td>USD 5000
    <tr>
        <td> JKL
        <td>USD 18000
    <tr>
        <td> MNO
        <td>USD 19000
    <tr>
        <td> PQR
        <td>USD 10500
        </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>'''
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
     0          1
0  ABC  USD 17000
1  DEF   USD 4000
2  GHI   USD 5000
3  JKL  USD 18000
4  MNO  USD 19000
5  PQR  USD 10500
```

**`.to_dict()`**

```
df_dict = pd.read_html(html)[0].to_dict()

print(df_dict)
{0: {0: 'ABC', 1: 'DEF', 2: 'GHI', 3: 'JKL', 4: 'MNO', 5: 'PQR'}, 1: {0: 'USD 17000', 1: 'USD 4000', 2: 'USD 5000', 3: 'USD 18000', 4: 'USD 19000', 5: 'USD 10500'}}
```